# widget and app in one apk

Tags: android, widget

I have an app and a widget. What must I do so that I can install just one thing. 
And not install the app and the widget separately?

I hope you understand me, otherwise just ask.

Gaauwe

Ps. I'm learning still English

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need to do is just declare both the widget and the app in the same AndroidManifest.xml.

Inside the application tag in your manifest, declare the app with an activity tag and the widget with the receiver tag.

Basically, try to "merge" both manifests into just one.

Please let me know if my answer was confusing to you.